# r error on installing colorspace for ggplot2

Tags: r

I am an r newbie and would appreciate some help installing ggplot2. I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1102.  Please see error below.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

runs fine

```
library("ggplot2")
```

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :  there is no package called ‘colorspace’ Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

```
install.packages("colorspace")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jessica/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) There is a binary version available (and
>   will be installed) but the source version is later: binary source
>   colorspace 1.2-4 1.2-5 trying URL
>   '...//cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/colorspace_1.2-4.zip'
>   Warning in install.packages : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not
>   Found' Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...)
>   :  cannot open URL
>   '...://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/colorspace_1.2-4.zip'
>   Warning in install.packages : download of package ‘colorspace’ failed

Comment: Add `SessionInfo()` output to your question. Just installed fine on R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), RStudio Version 0.99.235

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something is a bit messed up with the package meta-information or something in your Rstudio installation. A simple work-around to try is to just download the latest colorspace zip file from here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html

Then install by running `install.packages("c:/path/to/downloaded/zip/file/colorspace_1.2-5.zip")`

Answer (score 1):

When you type in `install.packages("ggplot2")` into the console, RStudio is pre-programmed to also install the dependencies (i.e. the other packages ggplot needs to run properly). In this case, the issue appears to be with the `colorspace` package not being able to installed. This is likely because you're running Yosemite and when RStudio looks to install colorspace, it searches for it on the CRAN, it can't find it for some reason:

```
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/colorspace_1.2-4.tgz'
```

You should be able to overcome this by installing the `colorspace` package yourself via the CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html.

Comment: This looks like very good advice; my system has a problem with this which I do not understand. I have been moving the zip file around trying to solve the problem, and nothing works: > install.packages("F:\colorspace_1.2-7.zip")  
Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""F:\c" Whatever follows the ID for the disc or memory gets the same error. Changing the backslash to a forward slash gives me different error statements.

Comment: The initial paragraph is incorrect. `install.packages("ggplot2")` does not automagically install dependencies. (And I also see no evidence this questioner was on a Mac.) Initially installing a missing package is often effective, though.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the original question, I recently encountered this issue with colormap 2.0.0, ggplot2 3.3.2, R 4.0.3, and RStudio 1.3.1093 on Windows. `install.packages("ggplot2")` reports success even though it does not install colormap and `library(ggplot2)` therefore fails. In my case, `install.packages("colormap")` failed to locate the 2.0.0 binaries, retrieving the 1.4.1 sources instead. Downloading the 2.0.0 binary from https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=colorspace, as suggested in other answers, failed with

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/<username>/Downloads/colorspace_2.0-0.zip") # note use of forward slashes to avoid the backlash escaping problems @Paul M mentions in his comment on @L P's answer -- \\ instead of just \ also works
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/Users/<username>/Downloads/colorspace_2.0-0.zip’ is not available for this version of R
```

What resolved this for me was including `type = "win.binary"` in `install.packages()`'s arguments when installing from the download.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/<username>/Downloads/colorspace_2.0-0.zip", type = "win.binary")
```

Having done this, `install.packages("colorspace")` also succeeds (both in session and after `remove.packages("colorspace")` and restarting R).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the color space separately and reload the package inside R studio again .

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
install.packages('colorspace')
library(ggplot2)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when the Curl version is not updated, problem with installing the packages happens. For resolving the problem in Linux, you could use the following command to update your Curl to tha last version:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it started giving this error when I updated all my packages using the available option "Packages" in R studio, it was working well before. After trying a few mentioned solutions in google and failed, I updated my R version and installed the packages, it worked.