# Get error on installing colorspace_2.0-3 from R Studio with R.4.2.1

Tags: r

I have an error when I try to install colorspace (it was ok few days ago) :

```
install.packages("colorspace")
```

I have this messsage :

```
Warning in install.packages : downloaded length 2594858 != reported length 2627626
Warning in install.packages : URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/colorspace_2.0-3.zip': status was 'Transferred a partial file'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/colorspace_2.0-3.zip' failed
Warning in install.packages : le téléchargement du package ‘colorspace’ a échoué
```

I have already tried the solution proposed here : [28887446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887446/r-error-on-installing-colorspace-for-ggplot2)

I notice I can't download the package source "colorspace_2.0-3.tar.gz" from
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/index.html or from http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/. I suppose this is not normal, correct ?

In addition, I can't install Rtools on my professional computer.

Thank you for your help !

Screenshot :
[download_error_chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP5X9.png)

Comment: Check your firewalls and such. When I download those links, I get the correct file size `2627626`, and the zip file is uncorrupted (as it appears to be in your case). If you download the file in your browser (not in R), do you get the incorrect file size there too?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. Yes I tried to download the file in my Brower (Chrome) and the file is incomplete. You can see the screenshot in my first post (download_error_chrome). I can download without error other package like ggplot2 from Chrome.

Comment: You could also try using a different CRAN mirror. Run ` chooseCRANmirror()` and choose a different server. (though normally cran.rstudio.com is very reliable). How big is the incomplete file you are getting? Can you open it in a text editor? I'm wondering if a firewall is blocking the request and returning an error message rather than the true file contents.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. Size of the incomplete file : 2 166 147 octets <  2 627 626. I can open with notepad but all the text is unreadable : something like "‹ J`b ì[y\ÇÛG±¢¨?OD­ÇEÍIE…ˆ¹b ¹\’%YH²q7K¬" ^^. I really think there is a problem with this specific package. I can dowload and install all the other package. Last modification of colorspace package :  2022-11-06 22:40  2.5M  ! 2 days ago. Before this date I had no problem. Really strange...